# String.format VB.NET Output

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, string.format

Working on `SerialPort.Write` in VB.NET for some reason I'm getting different results from

```
    Dim CommTXData As String
    CommTXData = String.Format("${0:D2}D" & vbCr, 99)
    SerialPort2.Write(CommTXData)
```

and

```
    Dim CommTXData As String
    CommTXData = "$99D"
    SerialPort2.Write(CommTXData)
```

They both have the same Output by checking with `Msgbox(CommTXData)` , it just that the first set of code works.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use `vbCr` in the first set of code and `vbCr` does not appear in the `Msgbox(CommTXData)` command.

```
 Dim CommTXData As String
CommTXData = "$99D" & vbCr
SerialPort2.Write(CommTXData)
```

`vbCr`    =   `Chr(13)`      =     Carriage return